# C++ compiler from VS2005

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, compiler-construction, sdk

If I would like to use the compiler that comes with Visual Studio 2005 but without IDE which Platform/Windows SDK should I install to get it? Windows SDK 2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this MSDN blog article:

- [Updated Windows SDK Visual C++ Cross Compilers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowssdk/archive/2007/09/08/updated-windows-sdk-visual-c-cross-compilers.aspx)

> The compilers in the new Windows Server 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5 SDK match (are exactly the same as) the compilers shipped with Visual Studio 2008.  In the Windows Vista RTM SDK or the Windows Vista Update SDK, the compilers matched the Visual Studio 2005 compilers.

You can find a link to the [Windows Vista Update SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=23719) in this Wikipedia article:

- [Microsoft Windows SDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_SDK)

Comment: Thanks, I found what I need on the Windows Vista Update SDK page.

Answer (score 1):

Download the [.NET Framework 2.0 Software Development Kit (SDK) (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=19988) for 2005.

Answer (score 0):

(For reference) If you have Visual Studio 2005 installed you can run one of the special command prompts they put in the start menu to get access to the command line compiler and tools.

Edit:

You can still find Visual Studio C++ 2005 Express Edition download in various places. That should contain the command line compilers. Otherwise try looking for a Visual C++ 2005 Toolkit download.

Comment: The thing is, I don't have VS2005 and cant use compiler from VC2010 express nor GCC/G++ :( (Matlab 2007 issue).